# Algorithm/Data Structure to determine if a word is a valid English word

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, tree, graph-algorithm

I'm designing an HTML5 game that requires me to validate that a word a user enters is a valid English word. I know I can perform the validation by sending the word to the server, however, since I want to do validation as the user types, server side validation is not an optimal solution. I therefore need to perform validation in the game, running in the user's browser.

What is the most efficient way for me to validate a user entered word, as the user types, against every word in the English language?

Comment: A trie? Can be done letter by letter as the user types.

Comment: What does "do validation as the user types" mean? Do you mean that if the user types "th", you take no action because there are words that start with "th", but if the user then types "f", then you'll somehow notify him that the input is invalid because there is no English word that starts with "thf"?

Comment: No. Validation means that whatever is currently displayed, as the user types, is validated to determine if it is a valid word. An onscreen indicator will constantly update as the user types. It will display red when the word is invalid and green when the word is valid. You might therefore have the case where, as the user types, the indicator might switch between red and green multiple times, depending on the word being typed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can use data structure such as trie where we make a tree of the searchable words and finds elements in `O(|P|)` time. Why trie is a better option if you ask yourself..you will see whenever user enters one character at a time you can traverse letter by letter on the fly and give fast feedback as per your game rule.

`P: pattern you are searching for.`

Also you said server side validation is not possible but I have seen games where they make ajax calls to validate words and at that time they create some thing that pops up on the screen or some game story or component to make you feel that it is happening instantly or in some interesting way,

Answer (score 1):

While a trie is the "theoretically correct" data structure to use, /usr/share/dict/words on my computer gzips to under 1 MB.  There are pure JS implementations of zlib which can be used to unzip that.  A binary search algorithm will take under 20 calls to find any particular word in the dictionary, which is more than fast enough for interactive use in the browser.

That's sufficient to implement this in the browser.

Answer (score 1):

A good algorithm for tasks like this is a [Bloom filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter). You should be aware that the hard part will be to assemble a suitable dictionary.

Comment: You'll need to describe how to use a Bloom filter for this, and you'll also need to address the false positives problem.